# Why isn't necessary the contextAPI in that case?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I thought that if I want to pass a state in another component, it is possible only through props or with contextAPI (provider etc).
For example:

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const FavContext = createContext();
//now we have a context object

function FavProvider(props) {
  //create the provider and its functionality
  const shape = {
    type: '', //films, planets, people
    id: 0, //id of film, or planet, or person
    data: {}, //the actual data object
  };
  const [fav, setFav] = useState(shape);

  function updateFav(type, id, data) {
    setFav({
      type,
      id,
      data,
    });
  }
  return <FavContext.Provider value={[fav, updateFav]} {...props} />;
}

function useFav() {
  //for pages that want to access the context object's value
  //custom hook use...
  const context = useContext(FavContext);
  if (!context) throw new Error('Not inside the Provider');
  return context; // [fav, updateFav]
}
export { useFav, FavProvider };
```

I wrap all the other components with the FavProvider, then I use the useFav wherever I want.

Here is a code without the contextAPI, and it works. Why is that? Why isn't necessary the contextAPI in that case?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';

export default function useAuthStatus() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [checkingStatus, setCheckingStatus] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
      }
      setCheckingStatus(false);
    });
  });
  return { loggedIn, checkingStatus };
}
```

and when I want to use the loggedIn and chekingStatus, I just bring it in like this:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import useAuthStatus from '../hooks/useAuthStatus';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

export default function PrivateRoutes() {
  const { loggedIn, checkingStatus } = useAuthStatus();
  if (checkingStatus) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return loggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/sign-in' />;
}
```

Comment: You have other way than context api to pass props to components child. Context is one oh them, and I think react-router-dom might actually use it in its internals. 
You could also achieve that by using high Order Component that would inject dependencies to all of its children.

But it woudl rise question about performance, et rerendering of components. (by the way, using context api does not fix rendering issue as Redux would ...)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use an array to pass the state through the value in the context API?